# Why use RegisterAssemblyTypes()?

Tags: autofac

I think that I have a fundamental misunderstanding of autofac. Consider the following autofac-using code

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(asm)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
       .As<IRepository>();
```

As I understand it, this code searches my assembly for all types that have names ending with `"Repository"` and tells the composition root that whenever I request an `IRepository`, I want one of those. However, I know that when you register multiple concrete types to the same abstraction, the last one that you register will be the one that you get when you resolve that abstraction. **In other words, the above call to `RegisterAssemblyTypes` will cause any request for an `IRepository` to be resolved to whatever the last concrete type the above code finds is**. Why would I ever want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about other use cases that aren't a single repository interface.

I have a command with a lot of handlers. I'll register all, then resolve `IEnumerable<IOrderHandler>`:

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(asm)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("OrderHandler"))
       .As<IOrderHandler>()
```

I have a system that supports plugins. Drop assemblies into the app and register all the implemented plugins.:

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(asm)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Plugin"))
       .As<IPlugin>()
```

I have a lot of different repository types, one of each, and want to register them all in one go. I'll resolve then one at a time - `IOrderRepository`, `IUserRepository`, etc.

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(asm)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
```

I have a bunch of controllers I want registered just as the type itself, no interfaces.

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(asm)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
```

Assembly scanning is great when you don't want to (or can't?) register everything explicitly and, instead, need to be more dynamic about it.

Note you can be way more dynamic than just looking at the name in that `Where` clause. You could look at the implemented interfaces (register all types that implement X), you could look at the base type (register all types that derive from Y)... I'm sure you can come up with some interesting ways to use assembly scanning to save some manual registration coding.

Comment: I don't understand the `.As<IPlugin>()` example. It's identical to the example in my question, so it has the same "If I'm registering everything, but only the last one matters, then why did I bother?" problem.

Comment: In a plugin system you usually have more than one plugin, right? You might only have one repository, but you'll have lots of plugins, and you'll resolve then as IEnunerable<T>, not just one. So... Not the same as your example at all. Different use case. Think less about "I only have one instance" and more about IEnumerable.

Comment: I think that's the key point. I've obviously missed (or perhaps the syntax has hidden), the distinction between registering (resolving?) for the sake of enumerables and registering for the sake of singletons.